# How to trigger a task in the Pipeline, by committing a file to ADO branch that drives the release in azure classic pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to be able to control which Artifacts to be included, and whether the Pipeline Tasks are triggered, by committing a file to ADO that drives the release. A file committed to ADO controls whether artifact task is triggered & artifact is included within the release. Committing a file to an ADO branch and running the pipeline against the build of that branch, will include the Artifacts and trigger the Tasks.

how to start with solving this question

Comment: Do you mean the *contents* of the file controls the artifact task, or just that the artifact task is triggered when a certain file is committed?

Comment: I have to create a file in ADO and assign a condition so that if we commit in file as per condition, our task will be triggered or not triggered. contents of file controls the artifact task